# Search for value in column 1 use value from coulmn 2 to find other rows with same values in column 2

Tags: sql

I have a simple database containing 3 tables.

```
Person (personId[PK], Name, other stuff)
Addresses (AddressId[PK], roade, number, other stuff)
Residents ( personId[FK],AddressId[FK]) The two columns are the PK
```

I need to be able to delete a person from the database and his address if he is the only one living there. So I need to be able to find out if more people live on the same address. If yes then let it remain if not delete the Address.

What I was thinking was

I want to delete a Person in the table Person using his name Delete person WHERE Name='John';
That should then also delete any row in Residents that matches Johns personId.
Now John also have one or more addresses, connected to him in the Residents table. Now when I delete John I need to delete any addresses he is connected to in the table Addresses.
As a last constraint I need to make sure that nobody else is connected to an address that I am about to delete. If there is another Person connected I should not delete the address in the table Addresses

Comment: OK. What have you already tried? Do you have `ON DELETE CASCADE` set on your tables?  What RDBMS do you use (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is to keep the `Addresses` table free of non-used entries, you can simply delete those rows that have no references in `Residents` (once you have removed the latter).

So, assuming your foreign keys are not defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, first you delete from `Residents`:

```
DELETE FROM Residents
WHERE personId IN (
  SELECT personId
  FROM Person
  WHERE Name = 'Name'
);
```

Then you can delete from `Adresses` like this:

```
DELETE FROM Addresses
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Residents
  WHERE Residents.AddressId = Addresses.AddressId
);
```

And, of course, you also delete the `Person` entry itself.

Answer (score 0):

To find addresses with more than one person:

```
select r.AddressId
from Residents r
group by r.AddressId
having count(*) > 1;
```

To get all the persons, you can do:

```
selects personId
from Residents r join
     (select r.AddressId
      from Residents r
      group by r.AddressId
      having count(*) > 1
     ) a
     on r.AddressId = a.AddressId;
```

Comment: Okay maybe I didn't make it as clear as I could have. I need to do the search on personId so I can find all the addressId connected to that personId. Then I need to know if any of the adressId exist for other personId so that I don't delete the address in the table Addresses

Comment: Okay first thanks for taking the time to help and sorry for me not being able to explain well enough or for not understanding what you wrote.